# Laravel4 Routing issue with controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
// My routes
Route::controller('api/v1/offer/{id?}', 'restful\OfferController');
Route::controller('api/v1/offer/{id}/qualifiers', 'restful\OfferController');
Route::controller('api/v1/offer/{id}/dishes', 'restful\OfferController');
Route::controller('api/v1/offer/{id}/choice/multiple', 'restful\OfferController');
Route::controller('api/v1/offer/{id}/choice/any', 'restful\OfferController');

// These works fine to me
'api/v1/offer/{id?}'           -> properly routes to OfferController::getIndex
'api/v1/offer/{id}/qualifiers' -> properly routes to OfferController::getQualifiers
'api/v1/offer/{id}/dishes'     -> properly routes to OfferController::getDishes

// ... but here i have problems.
'api/v1/offer/{id}/choice/multiple' -> routes to OfferController::choice
'api/v1/offer/{id}/choice/any'      -> routes to OfferController::choice
```

Why do in last 2 cases request is not routed to multiple/any method? How's the router logic in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two options here.

First one, is specifying your controller actions in your routes. Note that I'm using `Route::get()` and `@action`:

```
Route::get('api/v1/offer/{id}/choice/multiple', 'restful\OfferController@multiple');
Route::get('api/v1/offer/{id}/choice/any', 'restful\OfferController@any');
```

Second, let Laravel to wire any `api/v1/offer/{id}/choice` to `OfferController`:

```
Route::controller('api/v1/offer/{id}/choice', 'restful\OfferController');
```

If you use this second option, you have to define your actions like this in your controller (assuming they are `GET` requests):

```
class OfferController extends BaseController {

    public function getMultiple()
    {
        //
    }

    public function getAny()
    {
        //
    }


}
```